# How do I get my comments from local data.json to display on my page?

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch, jsx

Trying to load the comments from my local json file but can't seem to get it to load properly. It's currently just showing a bulleted list of "0, 1, 2". Any ideas?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import data from './../data'


class CommentList extends Component {
    render () {
      const elem = data.comments;

      return (
       <ul>
         {Object.keys(elem).map(s => (<li>{s}</li>))}
       </ul>
      )
    }
  };

export default CommentList
```

```
{
    "comments": [
      { 
        "text": "Australian Shepherd!"
      },
      { 
        "text": "German Shepherd!"
      },
      { 
        "text": "Mutts all the way"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

elem is an array so don't need `Object.keys`:

```
{elem.map(s => (<li>{s.text}</li>))}
```